# Nest-commander usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, nest, nest-commander

So am trying to use nest-commander to build seeder, how i so in examples and in docs, I must create src/commands folder, and then I create seed.command.ts file

```
import { Command, CommandRunner } from 'nest-commander';

@Command({
  name: 'my-exec',
  arguments: '<task>',
  options: { isDefault: true },
})
export class BasicCommand extends CommandRunner {
  async run(inputs: string[], options: Record<string, any>): Promise<void> {
    console.log('here will be my seeder');
  }
}
```

this is my main.ts file

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { CommandFactory } from 'nest-commander';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await CommandFactory.run(AppModule, ['warn', 'error']);

  app.enableCors();

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .addBearerAuth()
    .setTitle('CHS')
    .setDescription('CHS API')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`CHS is running on port: ${port} `, 'Bootstrap');
}
bootstrap();
```

and in app.module.ts file, I added BasicCommand in provides: [ BasicCommand ]

then i try to run this command-seeder file with this command: crun my-exec
but am getting this error: 2023-09-21T11:36:54.000556816Z: unknown command my-exec

Please can someone explain what am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the provider in your AppModule?

Try check this...

In your AppModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
   //your imports
  ],
  providers: [
     other providers...,
     ...NestCommands
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Where NestCommands is:

```
export const NestCommands = [
    BasicCommand,
    other commands...
];
```